# Is it possible to update a table in MySQL from a trigger in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, oledb

Is it possible to connect MS SQL to MySQL database?

I want to write a trigger after insert in SQL and update a table in mysql. I have tried to use `sp_addlinkedserver`, but I was not successful.

Comment: Nope, not possible. You'll have to script it with some outside language.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @wogsland mssql can make a "linked" (?) table connection to a MySQL server, and integrate remote tables into the local schemata, similar to the way "federated" connections allow a table on one MySQL server to be accessed across the wire by another MySQL server as if they were local, so why is this not possible?  Does the mssql implementation prevent such a table from being a target of a trigger action?  That seems arbitrary, if true.